# Conditional constraints in Cplex

Tags: python, optimization, time, constraints, cplex

I am very new to CPlex optimization and Python and I am trying to solve an optimization problem.

Now I have a DataFrame called **df_current** that looks like this:
[Current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/233fT.png)
Have defined the model and the variables as under:

```
m = Model(name="Hedge optimization")
seven_24 = m.continuous_var(name = '7x24 block')
seven_16 = m.continuous_var(name = '7x16 block')
five_16 = m.continuous_var(name = '5x16 block')
hour = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,23]
sum = df_current['volume'].sum(axis=1)
dow = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']
```

Now I want the constraints for the seven_16 and five_16 to be as under:

**seven_24_constraint: seven_24 > 200 and <=450**

**seven_16_constraint: seven_16 = 0 if Hour column in the dataframe matches any value in the hour variable**

**five_16_constraint: five_16 = 0 if Hour and Day column in the dataframe matches any value in the hour and dow variables respectively**

I am trying to define them as under:

```
seven_24constraint = m.add_constraint(seven_24 > 200 & seven_24 <=450)
seven_16constraint = m.add_constraint(seven_16 = 0 if df_current['Hour'] in hour)
five_16constraint = m.add_constraint(five_16 = 0 if (df_current['Hour'] in hour && df_current['Day'] in dow)
```

But it is giving me an error.

If I can debug this error, my goal is to write a minimization function as under

`goal = m.minimize(sum - seven_24*364*24 - seven_16*364*16 - five_16*260*16)`

To put more perspective, the variables, seven_24, seven_16 and five_16 can be visualized as under:

**7x24  Mon to Sun (24 Hours)**

**7x16  Mon to Sun (7 am to 11 pm)**

**5x16  Mon to Fri (7 am to 11 pm)**

How can I debug the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

First, in your constraints you cannot use python assignment (=) but you should use the equality operator (==) which is overloaded for python variables.

You say 'hour' is a variable but it is declared as a constant array, it is confusing.
If you actually want to add a conditional constraints please consider using 'add_if_then' from http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html

Comment: Hello sir. Thank you for your answer. I am actually trying to assign the constraint and not comparing it. What I am trying to do here is assign variables seven_16 and five_16 a ZERO value if the condition is satisfied. Basically I just want the above two variables only to be considered for optimization if the values in the data frame column “hour” falls matches with any of the values in “hour array” for seven_16. For five_16, both the previous condition and the value of the day column in the df should match any value of the “dow array”